# how to use class as datatype without NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#

I have some when I create my application when I try to use the resourceID From Topic I get this error NullReferenceException  my Question is how to use Resource as datatype in Topic object without NullReferenceException

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=test
  StackTrace:
       at test.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Abdalla\Desktop\BOL\BOL\test\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using BOL;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Topic t = new Topic();

            t.Id = 1;
            t.Drescription = "Topic Drescription ";
            t.Resource.ResourceID = 1;


            Console.WriteLine("ResourceID" + t.Resource.ResourceID.ToString());
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BOL
{
    class Topic
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Drescription { get; set; }
        public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BOL
{
    class Resource
    {
        public int ResourceID { get; set; }
        public string Res_summary { get; set; }
        public string PageID { get; set; }
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        public Resource() { }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instantiate 'Resource` it before using it, e.g. `t.Resource = new Resource();`

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resource` is a reference to an object of type `Resource`. Since you did not specify a constructor, by default it will be set to `null` since it is a `class`.

`t.Resource.ResourceID` attempts to set the `ResourceID` of the `Resource` object, which since you have not created, will be `null`. This creates the `NullReferenceException` that you are seeing.

You need to initialize `t.Resource` before you access it. There are two ways to do this:

1. Add a constructor to `Topic` that calls the default constructor of `Resource`
2. Initialize `Resource` in `Main`

In either case you need to add the following line: `Resource = new Resource();` (potentially prefixed with `t.`)

Since the former appears to line up with your expectations, here is `Topic` with the constructor added.

```
class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Drescription { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }

    public Topic()
    {
        Resource = new Resource();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Resource` object first:

```
t.Resource = new Resource();
t.Resource.ResourceID = 1;
```

Or do it in the constructor of the Topic:

```
class Topic
{
    public Topic()
    {
        this.Resource = new Resource();
    }
    ...
}
```